# VBA GetCursorPos X/Y location on active window not desktop

Tags: vba

I'm using GetCursorPos in some VBA code and it works well but not when the application is not opened full screen. The X/Y location is based on the mouse desktop location not the location in the application window. Is there a way have it base the X/Y location on the active window or app that the VBA is running in?

I don't know lots about VBA and this in a SCADA application not MS Office.

I found this code but it's not working:

```
Private Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
    Private Type POINTAPI
        X As Long
        Y As Long
    End Type
    Dim Mouse As POINTAPI
    Dim Cmd As String
    Dim PNum As String

Private Declare Function ClientToScreen Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long


Private Sub Button3_Released()
    GetCursorPos Mouse
    ScreenToClient Me.Application.WindowHandle, Mouse
    MsgBox Mouse.X
End Sub
```

Now it works!

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to map it to window coordinates with [ScreenToClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-screentoclient).

Comment: ScreenToClient don't seem to be in VBA.

Comment: No, it's not - It's a library function like `GetCursorPos`. You'll need to declare it.

Comment: Added what I found to the OP but not sure of the syntax to get it working.